How to scale a sequential source in dataflow / beam?
The question is about a sequentially emitting source in dataflow?
For example the bigqueryio go implementaion is very basic. It reads a query resuls in a loop and emits records sequentially. Therefore dataflow is not scaling the amount of workers and detects a straggler.
Pseudocode of such custom DoFn in Java:

@ProcessElement
public void processElement(@Element byte[] input, OutputReceiver<T> output) throws Exception {
        // ..
        result = bigquery.query(queryConfig);
        for (FieldValueList row : result.iterateAll()) {    
            output.output(mapRowToType(row));
        }
}

Subsequent steps which consume the source in a ParDo are never scaled. The docs hint this can happen if the custom source does not implement progress (which it does not).
Example Transform of the above source in Java:
var bigqueryRows = pipeline.apply("ReadFromBigQuery", BigQueryIO.read(//...));
var mutations = bigqueryRows.apply("ProcessRows", ParDo.of(/**/ {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(@Element ItemRow row, OutputReceiver<BigtableIO.Write.Mutation> out) {

        String rowKey = row.getId(); 
        BigtableIO.Write.Mutation mutation = BigtableIO.Write.Mutation.create(rowKey);
        // ...
        out.output(mutation);
    }
}));


How to deal with such sequential source, if there is no other option to consume the data.
Is there a strategy one can add later to the pipeline so that it starts paralellizing the processing to multiple workers?
*NOTE:
Even though my particular problem is with go sdk and bigqueryio, my question is about such a scenario in general. Feel free to provide a generic answer in any familiar beam language sdk.

Not familiar with the GO implementations. But in general, https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/developing-io-overview/ has more information. https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#splittable-dofns should be the way to go.

thx for the hint. That is exactly the issue. The golang bigqueryio is not written in a splitable way. I figured out, that beam supports parallelesm but not concurrency.  Hence an io source cannot be consumed while it is still reading records. The only thing beam can do is schedule other processesing functions into the reading stage via fusing. So the only way to add better parallelism is to reimplement this golang bigquerio to also support the splitable bigquery streaming api like other clients do.

Yes. I am not sure whether you can use cross-lang with Go to access the BQ Java API.

I'm experiencing a similar issue in https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/33229. The data isn't processed until the I close the Websocket and the pipeline drains.
"Hence an io source cannot be consumed while it is still reading records." I've gotten it to work though a splittable DoFn, but as a Websocket is sequentially implementing data, it's not ideal.
